# Create table field with foreign key constraint

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, relational-database

I want to create a table `department`:

```
COLUMN NAME   DATATYPE    SIZE   CONSTRAINT

dept_id       number      4      Primary key
prod_id       number      4      Foreign key
```

I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE Department(
dept_id number(4) primary key,
prod_id number(4) foreign key);
```

It shows error. How can I add a foreign key constraint to this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key defines a relationship between your table DEPARTMENT and **another table** with a primary key. It means, *you cannot create a row in DEPARTMENT with a PROD_ID of 1234 unless there is a pre-existing row in the designated parent table with a value of 1234 as its primary key*.

So do you have such an existing parent table? if so you need to include its name in the foreign key definition. Otherwise you must create it.

Let's say the parent table is PRODUCT:

```
create table product (
    prod_id number(4) primary key
    , name varchar2(32) not null 
);
```

Then you can create DEPARTMENT with a foreign key like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Department(
    dept_id number(4) primary key,
    prod_id references PRODUCT );
```

Yep, that's all the syntax you need: it automatically creates a column PROD_ID with the same datatype and precision as the primary key column of the referenced table. More verbose syntax is available. Read the Oracle SQL documentation to [find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the other table is named `other_table_name` and that it contains a primary key named `prod_id`.

```
CREATE Department (
dept_id number(4) primary key,
prod_id number(4) REFERENCES other_table_name (prod_id)
);
```

or a different syntax

```
CREATE Department (
dept_id number(4) primary key,
prod_id number(4)

...
CONSTRAINT fk_prod_id
  FOREIGN KEY (prod_id)
  REFERENCES other_table_name (prod_id)
);
```

Comment: You need to substitute your actual referenced table in place of @Ely's example, `other_table_name`.

Comment: @diya You must make sure of course that the referenced table and column are created before you create the actual reference. I thought this was clear (it makes sense if you think about it).